# Redirect everyone but for a few to index.html or http://www.example.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ip

I am soon going to be setting up a new website, but while I do that I would like to put up an index.html, so everyone sees it, but if they try and visit another file abc.html for example they are redirect back to index.html or http://www.example.com

No, I want to be able to view any file, so I was wondering about checking IP and if IPs are allowed to view, let them see any file, if they not in the list, send them to index.html or http://www.example.com

I presume I would use .htaccess for something like this, but not sure of what to put in.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to do more than use .htaccess? If you have access to the config files for apache (and can restart apache - i.e. this is on a virtual/dedicated server rather than a shared server) then you could set up a separate host for it.

Comment: Another alternative is just to allow anyone to see anything (don't bother with the redirect) and just set up basic authentication so you can see what you like and others can't. Save yourself time!

Comment: I am  on shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Redirect everyone but for me
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^127\.0\.0\.1
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com [R=302,L]
```

Would that work, I would change the IP to mine instead of 127.0.0.1?

Or would it cause a loop as I would be working on example.com?

Comment: This should cause a loop. But you could redirect it to another folder where you disable this rule. Then, everyone will onyl see the index-file in this folder instead of the real website.
If you use a relativ path and delete the "R=302", the redirect will not be visible in the url